# Undefined Intersection constructor

Tags: javascript, animation

I tried using the intersection observer to animate my page on scroll but the browser keeps saying the intersection constructor isn't defined. Please I need help sorting this out.

```js
let animate = document.querySelector(".slide");
let observer = new Intersection( (entries) => {
  console.log(entries);
});

observer.observe(animate);
```

[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKWHF.png)

Comment: The intersection observer constructor is named [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver). So, no `Intersection` does not exist.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not Intersection class in JavaScript, the correct class name is `IntersectionObserver`, try referencing it correctly:

```js
let observer = new IntersectionObserver( (entries) => {
  console.log(entries);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was an omission on my part.